# I would like to pull desired info from outlook to excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I receive lots of emails daily all in the same format and would like to pull of certain parts of the email into an excel spread sheet. see below

From: random@email.com 
**Sent: Friday, February 27, 2015 4:10 AM**
To: -NOT REQUIRED-
Subject:-NOT REQUIRED-
Source: -NOT REQUIRED-

An application has been made for the following job ad.

Title:      -NOT REQUIRED-
**Location:     Sydney**
Date Posted:    -NOT REQUIRED-
**Your Reference:   3531- Friday 20th**
Description:    We are a specialist recruiter of people with customer service experience who are looking to move into a rewarding opening.

==================================================

## Applicant

**Name             : example name

  Phone            : example phone number

  Email            : example@email.address**

the info I need is in bold I have never done this before and have no idea where to start so any help would be greatly appreciated. many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Do you have any code outlining your attempt?

Comment: Getting `Sent` info is easy. It is a property of the [`mailitem object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861332.aspx). As for the body, if those keywords are fixed, then you can extract those by working on the `.Body` property of the `mailitem object`. Try something out and post your code here if you got stuck in the process.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA outlook body string search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001670/vba-outlook-body-string-search)

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001670/vba-outlook-body-string-search . This code-free question currently has two downvotes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25140954/copy-data-in-a-structured-text-block-from-outlook-message-to-excel-sheet . Why should you consider deleting your question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258757/how-can-i-understand-why-am-i-receiving-a-warning-that-i-could-be-blocked

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unforunately we're a question and answer site for professional or enthusiast programmers, not a code-writing service, you'd need a freelance programmer for that. With that in mind your question as it is looks more like a work request than y'know... a _question_. If you've made an attempt at this yourself and are running into problems then by all means show us your attempt and explain what's going wrong, otherwise this question will need to be closed as it's not a specific, practical and answerable question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to automate Outlook from Excel to extract the required information. See [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/201096?wa=wsignin1.0) for more information.

But if you need to handle each incoming mail item you may consider developing a VBA macro or add-in. Note, VBA macros are not designed for distributing on multiple PCs. So, you can create a rule in Outlook which may trigger a VBA sub where you can extract all the required information into an Excel workbook. For example:

```
public sub test(mail as MailItem)
   ' do whatever you need
end sub
```

Also you may consider handling the [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Application class which is fired when a new item is received in the Inbox.

Finally, you may find the following articles helpful:

- [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Visual Basic](http://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/219151)
- [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Microsoft Visual C#.NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/302084?wa=wsignin1.0)